# Событие для <option> , изменить шрифт текста с <option>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Есть такой код:

```
<select>
    <option>some txt</option>
</select>
```

Нужно к тегу `option` сделать событие `onclick="func()"`, но что-то не выходит.

P.S. Не обязательно событие - нужно, чтобы при выборе он менял шрифт текста.

Comment: Можно в цикле попробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это на изменение состояния `select`,

```js
var sel = document.querySelector('select');
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// No click only onchange event 
sel.addEventListener('change', function (e) { 
  if(sel.value == 'Audi'){
  // do what you need here
   console.log('Doing....... ' + sel.value);
  }
  console.log('Changed ', sel.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно только менять стиль `option`, то можно обойтись и без `js`.

Изменение стиля только средствами `css`

```css
select#mySelect {
  color: red;
}

select#mySelect option:not(:checked) {
  color: black;
}

select#mySelect2 option:checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect2">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```